# Alamofire variables or parameters support in url path

Tags: swift, alamofire

Does Alamofire support variables in a url path, I have looked for an example but i can't find it.
I have looked in their their docs and unit tests.
It is pretty common for apis to be written with url support for the following:

```
http://someapi.com/users/{user}/profile
```

I have looked through their examples in URLEncoding, but i cant find nothing that does the above, examples only seem to add query parameters.

Comment: Do you want to include parameter in the URL like this? `let url = URL(string: "http://someapi.com/users/useid1252/profile")`. If so then you can make URL like above and pass this URL to `URLRequest`

Comment: Yes i know, but its not uncommon for rest frameworks to support variables in urls. I just want to make sure i am not building the url manually if alamofire suports it.

Comment: Okay, got your question. Yes, we will have to build URL manually like you are doing, there is no extra support from Alamofire for it.. You are on right path :D

Comment: Yes that’s what I wanted to know. Didn’t wanted to build something if alamofire supported it.

Answer (score 2):

Alamofire relies on the Foundation [URL](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/url) struct, so you need to look there.

URLs offer several different mechanisms for constructing them, the one you could be using is [path component](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/url/1780397-appendpathcomponent), for example:

```
var url = URL(string: "http://someapi.com/users")
let user = "user"
url?.appendPathComponent(user)
url?.appendPathComponent("profile")
```

Additionally, you could leverage enums to clean up a bit and maybe construct URLs from strings, something like this:

```
enum MyURLScheme {
    case profile(user: String)

    var url: URL? {
        switch self {
        case .profile(let user):
            let url = URL(string: "http://someapi.com/users/\(user)/profile")
            return url
        }
    }
}

let profileURL = MyURLScheme.profile(user: "user").url
```

EDIT: You can also use Alamofire Router class for building requests, [taken from here](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/AdvancedUsage.md):

```
enum Router: URLRequestConvertible {
    case search(query: String, page: Int)

    static let baseURLString = "https://example.com"
    static let perPage = 50

    // MARK: URLRequestConvertible

    func asURLRequest() throws -> URLRequest {
        let result: (path: String, parameters: Parameters) = {
            switch self {
            case let .search(query, page) where page > 0:
                return ("/search", ["q": query, "offset": Router.perPage * page])
            case let .search(query, _):
                return ("/search", ["q": query])
            }
        }()

        let url = try Router.baseURLString.asURL()
        let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url.appendingPathComponent(result.path))

        return try URLEncoding.default.encode(urlRequest, with: result.parameters)
    }
}

Alamofire.request(Router.search(query: "foo bar", page: 1))
```

Comment: Alamofire provides several extensions around URLRequest and URL , while i like your enum approach i just wanted to know if alamofire has that functionality.

Comment: i think ur edit adds query parameters but in ur link they suggest something similar to ur first enum using URLConvertible

https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/AdvancedUsage.md#type-safe-routing